# Performance issue with select distinct top 10 in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, query-performance

I'm trying to move the logic which works correctly in the `WHERE` clause below, to the `FROM` clause, due to severe performance issues with it in the `WHERE` clause. I have tried several variations of `INNER JOIN` or `CROSS APPLY` but have not gotten it to work.

```
with PtsPerUnit (Department, MRN) as
     (select Department, MRN 
      from eMetrics
     )
 select *
 from eMetrics eM
 where eM.mrn in 
       (select distinct top 10 mrn 
        from PtsPerUnit ppu 
        where ppu.department = eM.department
       )
```

The end goal is to filter the dataset down to only 10 `MRNs` per `Department`.

In other words, select all the rows of the table but only up to 10 different `MRNs` per `Department`. So if there are 13 different `MRNs` for a department, select 10 `MRNs`, chosen arbitrarily, and all the rows of those department-MRN combinations. For another department that may have 20 different `MRNs`, again select only 10 `MRNs` and all the rows that match those department-MRN combinations, and the same for all remaining departments.

This is an example of the final dataset that I would like to query off of 
 (where I can pull all records with RowNum <= 10) and have it perform
 reasonably well.

```
Dept    MRN Metric      Value RowNum
Surg1   M1  Scale 1       5     1               -- dept 1
Surg1   M1  Scale 2       3     1
Surg1   M1  Scale 1       0     1
Surg1   M2  Scale 4       2     2
Surg1   M2  Scale 9       0     2
        .                       .
        .                       .
Surg1   M10 Scale 9       7    10
Surg1   M10 Scale 6       0    10
---
Surg2   Q1  Scale 3       5     1               -- dept 2
Surg2   Q1  Scale 2       3     1
Surg2   Q1  Scale 1       0     1
Surg2   Q2  Scale 4       2     2
Surg2   Q2  Scale 3       0     2
        .                       .
        .                       .
Surg2   Q10 Scale 8       7    10
Surg2   Q10 Scale 6       0    10
---
    ..
    ..
---
Surg103   G1  Scale 2       5       1            -- dept 3
Surg103   G1  Scale 4       3       1
Surg103   G1  Scale 1       0       1
Surg103   G2  Scale 6       2       2
Surg103   G2  Scale 2       0       2
        .                   .
        .                   .
Surg103   G10 Scale 4       7      10
Surg103   G10 Scale 2       0      10
```

Comment: What is an MRN? Does it have a primary table where it's not duplicated so you can avoid the distinct? What does your TOP mean without ORDER BY? Can you provide some sample data and desired results, including which rows to leave out where a department has more than 10 MRNs, and what should happen when a department has less than 10, and also how to handle ties.

Comment: Using TOP without ORDER BY is only because we are pulling a random sample of data. I will respond to your post below with more detail.

Comment: [PLEASE READ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try Aaron's query with `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`: `rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY Department ORDER BY mrn)`

Comment: That is the desired output, but I still don't understand the input.

Comment: @rdbdba - It's often said that no specific order is guarantee in the results of a `SELECT` without an `ORDER BY`. While that is true, neither does the DB engine provide a truly random order. the order of the result set is based on how the engine processes the query. It is possible that, in a department with 20 MRNs, the same ten would show up every time you ran the report for months; then, something would change how the data's stored, or how the query is processed, and you'll get another ten - who will then repeat regularly. If you need a truly random selection, you need something else.

Comment: @rdbdba I edited your question and added an explanation - as I understand the question. Please check if it is what you want or edit accordingly. Since you mention performance in the question, I added the tag. Please also edit the question and add the `CREATE TABLE` definition and the indexes you have.

Comment: Regarding performance, do you have an index on `(department, MRN)`? I'm not sure if it's going to be used, as the query will probably return a very large part of the table (depending on the distribution of the  values) so the optimizer may choose a table scan anyway but it may help.

Comment: It is a view, and the table it pulls from is not indexed on department and/or MRN. I'm trying to determine some logic now to look at the previous MRN, if it is the same as the current MRN, then don't increment a counter, but if it's different then increment.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one MRN per department, you just need to plug in how you want to define "top 10":

```
;WITH PtsPerUnit AS 
(
  SELECT Department, MRN, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY Department ORDER BY <???something???>) 
  FROM dbo.Emetrics
)
SELECT Department, MRN 
  FROM PtsPerUnit 
  WHERE rn <= 10
  ORDER BY Department, <???something???>;
```

If the `DISTINCT` really is necessary, you're going to need to provide sample data and desired results, but maybe this will work instead (you're still going to have to implement the ordering column):

```
;WITH PtsPerUnit AS 
(
  SELECT Department, MRN, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY Department, MRN ORDER BY <???something???>) 
  FROM dbo.Emetrics
)
SELECT Department, MRN 
  FROM PtsPerUnit 
  WHERE rn <= 10
  ORDER BY Department, <???something???>;
```

As @ypercube pointed out, if this doesn't give the answers you want, you could experiment with other ranking functions other than `ROW_NUMBER()`, like `DENSE_RANK()`. The important piece that's missing, still, is what to order by; that will dictate which (up to) 10 rows you get per department. If you want a random order, use `ORDER BY NEWID()`, but don't expect that to be blazing fast.

Comment: There are multiple MRNs per department and multiple records per MRN, so we are trying to pull 10 MRNs per department with all of the associated records for each MRN. I have also tried variations of ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION...) to no avail.

Comment: @rdbdba We don't know what variations you've tried or what to no avail means. Please add sample data and desired results to your question so we can know how to solve your problem. [PLEASE READ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).